# Getting Current Date and Time of a Specific Country

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, timezone

i need to get Turkey's (Istanbul) date and time from a server in another country. So i can use it in my asp.net project and add it to my sql server database. Can you help me please ?

Comment: You can send it from client. That single way you can get local time on server

Comment: @OlegYudovich what if client is in another country too? There must be a way.

Comment: Help what? Can't you use time zone?

Comment: @MaciejLos This didn't help me.

Comment: You want always save time in turkey time?

Comment: @OlegYudovich Not always. When users click a button.

Comment: @wanxpy, you can get the difference to utc. Knowing the time zone for Turkey, you can calculate current date and time in Turkey. Got it?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.findsystemtimezonebyid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
var info = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Turkey Standard Time");
DateTimeOffset localServerTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;
DateTimeOffset localTime= TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(localServerTime, info);
```

Comment: How can i convert DateTimeOffset(10.05.2015 01:48:06 +03:00) to DateTime (10.05.2015 01:48:06) ?

Comment: From datetomeOffset property LocalDateTime :istambulTime.LocalDateTime

Comment: Read this MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.localdatetime

Comment: @OlegYudovich - `.LocalDateTime` will convert it back to the server's time zone.  Just use the `.DateTime` property.

Answer (score 2):

You can get Turkey time this way:

```
 // Get time in local time zone 
 DateTime thisTime = DateTime.Now;
 Console.WriteLine("Time in {0} zone: {1}",
        TimeZoneInfo.Local.IsDaylightSavingTime(thisTime) ?
        TimeZoneInfo.Local.DaylightName : TimeZoneInfo.Local.StandardName, thisTime);
 Console.WriteLine("   UTC Time: {0}",
        TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(thisTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local));

 // Get GTB Standard Time zone - (GMT+02:00) Athens, Istanbul, Minsk
 TimeZoneInfo tst = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GTB Standard Time");
 DateTime tstTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(thisTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local, tst);      
 Console.WriteLine("Time in {0} zone: {1}",
        tst.IsDaylightSavingTime(tstTime) ?
        tst.DaylightName : tst.StandardName, tstTime);
 Console.WriteLine("   UTC Time: {0}",
        TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(tstTime, tst));
```

For further information, please see:
[TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.findsystemtimezonebyid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) 
[Microsoft Time Zone Index Values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms912391%28v=winembedded.11%29.aspx)